# ThreadGroup.activeCount() method is not working in java

Tags: java, multithreading, threadgroup

I am learning the concept of multi-threading, where i was trying to find the number of active threads in an array, but the method of ***ThreadGroup.activeCount()*** is only returning zero value for it.

Here is the code:

**Thread object class** :-

```
class th1 extends Thread
{
    public th1(String threadName, ThreadGroup tg1)
    {
        super(tg1, threadName);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is running");
    }
}
```

**main class** :-

```
public class enumerate_demo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ThreadGroup tg1 = new ThreadGroup("group 1");

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new th1("t-1", tg1));
        t1.start();

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new th1("t-2", tg1));
        t2.start();

        Thread t3 = new Thread(new th1("t-3", tg1));
        t3.start();

        System.out.println("Number of active count :- " + tg1.activeCount());

        Thread[] group = new Thread[tg1.activeCount()];

        int count = tg1.enumerate(group);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Thread " + group[i].getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that while creating instances `th1` class you are using them as `Runnable` as oppose to `Thread`. And those wrapper threads aren't associated with any `ThreadGroup` . Declare variables as follows.

```
        Thread t1 = new th1("t-1", tg1);
        t1.start();
```

Comment: So? It doesn't make any difference. There are still hatred three ads in the same thread group.